Compare different rows in SQL of the same table and retrieve one result after a specified order
For suppose lets consider the below set of table



Class
Key
rule
version
RuleAvailable




Class 1
Class1-Csx -02.01
Csx
02.01
Yes


Class1
Class1- Csx -01.01
Csx
01.01
Yes


Class1
Class1-CsxBusrule -01.01
CsxBusrule
01.01
Withdrawn


Class1
Class1 - Csxfw -01.01
Csxfw
01.01
Yes


Class2
Class2 - Csx - 02.01
Csx
02.01
Yes


Class2
Class2 - Csxbusrule -02.01
Csxbusrule
02.01
Yes


Class3
Class3 - Csxfw -01.01
Csxfw
01.01
Yes



Here, firstly we have to do partition of class and then rule and then by version
CSXBusrule>> CSX >> CSXFW
For each Unique Class, if we have three rules Csx ,CsxBusrule , Csxfw we should take Csxbusrule into consideration and then return the higher version of it. and if the higher version of Csxbusrule is withdrawn, we should not take any rows in csxbusrule, we should ignore csxbusrule and then take csx as per order
If for a class there is only rule Csxfw, higher version of that row should be returned
Below is the expected result



Class
Key
RUle
Version
ruleavailable




Class 1
Class1-CsxBusrule -01.01
Csx
01.01
Yes


Class2
Class2 - Csx- 02.01
Csxbusrule
02.01
Yes


Class3
Class3 - Csxfw-01.01
Csxfw
01.01
Yes



Select Key ,Class , Rule , Version FROM 
(SELECT t.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY class ORDER BY CASE rule WHEN 'CSXBusRule' THEN 1 WHEN 'CSX' THEN 2 WHEN 'CSXFW' THEN 3 END, version DESC) AS rn FROM table t where 
pyRuleAvailable='Yes') WHERE rn = 1

tried this, but this doesn't include withdrawn logic, we have to ignore the rule and go with next rule order if the higher version of that rule is withdrawn

As per this answer of the linked duplicate - you can solve it using the ROW_NUMBER analytic function like this fiddle

Your edit doesn't change the solution much, just wrap the rule in a CASE expression to set the different priorities fiddle (and the question is a duplicate)
